# How can I separate the number from the unit in argument?

Tags: macros, lengths, unit-of-measure

Let us say that I have a function, in which I give a number plus a unit. I would like to get only the number, is it possible ?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{#1} % change here to capture only the number.  
\begin{document}
    \cmd{12pt} % print 12pt while I would get only 12, in a generic case.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\def\cmd#1pt{#1}
\begin{document}
    \cmd12pt 
\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot - That'll work for `pt` as the unit, but for `em`, `mm`, `km`, etc. :-)

Comment: @Mico Yes, I know. But it does answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgf` does that without the need to invoke external programs and converts the units into points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult} 
\begin{document}
    \cmd{12pt} \cmd{1cm} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that if you're bugged by the `.0`: this can easily be removed with `\pgfmathprintnumber[<your number format here>]{pgfmathresult}` if you choose a number format that you like.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the unit consists of two characters, you can do it in an expandable way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getnumber}{m}
 {
  \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { -3 } % from the first to the last but two character
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getnumber{12pt}, $\getnumber{-47km}$, \getnumber{+5.7in}, \getnumber{3,14159CM}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could `\getnumber` be generalized, say by taking an integer as an optional argument (with the default value of the optional argument set to 2), to handle cases of units which contain a number of characters not equal to 2? E.g., `\getnumber[3]{5.678mol}` or `\getnumber[1]{1.23m}`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It sets up a LaTeX macro called `\cmd` -- a "wrapper" -- that invokes a Lua function that does all of the work. The Lua function expects its argument to consist of two parts: the first part is numeric, i.e., consists of the digits `0` thru `9`, plus possibly the characters `,`, `.`, `-`, and `+`; the part second is alphabetic, i.e., uppercase and lowercase letters, plus possibly whitespace.

Per your typesetting objective, the function returns just the numeric, part. If the argument of `\cmd` does not start with a numeric component, the prefix part is discarded as well. E.g., the output of `\arg{XX55km}` is `55`, and the output of `\cmd{km}` is blank (empty).

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
function get_num ( s )
  tex.sprint ( ( s:gsub ( "([%d%.%,%-%+]*)([%a%s]*)" , "%1" ) ) )
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\cmd[1]{\directlua{get_num("#1")}}  % "wrapper" macro

\begin{document}
\cmd{12pt}, $\cmd{-47km}$, \cmd{+5.7in}, \cmd{3,14159CM}
\end{document}
```